# How can I send multiple emails to different individuals in appscripts

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

```
function reminder() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues()
  var d = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i=1;i<data.length;i++){
    if (data[i][4]<=new Date(d+7*24*60*60*1000) && data[i][4]>=new Date(d+5*24*60*60*1000) && data[i][6]==''){
      MailApp.sendEmail({to:data[i][3],
        subject: 'Reminder Process Update Required in 1 week',
        htmlBody: 'Hello '+data[i][2]+', the  process page for <b>'+data[i][1]+'</b> is due for review in 1 week. Please review the content and contact the Process team before its due date if amendments are required.'
      })
      sh.getRange(i+1,7).setValue('sent')
    }
    else if (data[i][4]<=new Date(d+30*24*60*60*1000) && data[i][4]>=new Date(d+28*24*60*60*1000) && data[i][5]==''){
      MailApp.sendEmail({to:data[i][3],
        subject: 'Reminder Process Update Required in 1 month',
        htmlBody: 'Hello '+data[i][2]+', the process page for <b>'+data[i][1]+'</b> is due for review in review in 1 month. Please review the content and contact the Process Mapping team before its due date if amendments are required.'
      })
      sh.getRange(i+1,6).setValue('sent')
    }
  }
}
```

So currently its sending an email to "data[i][3]" I would also like to add up to 2 further recipients that it would email alongside what is there but also if these fields are left blank it should then only issue the email to the field that is filled in.

Heres a link to the demo of the sheet and script - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qw8WefbVkS-AQXi1CcZ0z2CL-P0oNSZYqeT40oVF6go/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to use the recipient email addresses of the values of columns "D" to "F".
- In your showing script, you are using the columns "A" to "G". In this case, the email address is the column "D". But in your question, the email addresses are the columns "D" to "F". And, you want to use the columns "A" to "I". Namely, you added 2 columns to the showing script.

In this case, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

In this modification, the values of columns "D" to "F" are used as the recipient email addresses. When the values of columns "D" to "F" are no values, `MailApp.sendEmail` is not run. And, for your new structure of Spreadsheet, the index for each row in the for loop was modified.

```
function reminder() {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var data = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var d = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var recipients = data[i].slice(3, 6).filter(String).join(",");
    if (recipients == "") continue;
    if (data[i][6] <= new Date(d + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) && data[i][6] >= new Date(d + 5 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) && data[i][7] == '') {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: recipients,
        subject: 'Reminder Process Update Required in 1 week',
        htmlBody: 'Hello ' + data[i][2] + ', the  process page for <b>' + data[i][1] + '</b> is due for review in 1 week. Please review the content and contact the Process team before its due date if amendments are required.'
      });
      sh.getRange(i + 1, 9).setValue('sent');
    }
    else if (data[i][6] <= new Date(d + 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) && data[i][6] >= new Date(d + 28 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) && data[i][7] == '') {
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: recipients,
        subject: 'Reminder Process Update Required in 1 month',
        htmlBody: 'Hello ' + data[i][2] + ', the process page for <b>' + data[i][1] + '</b> is due for review in review in 1 month. Please review the content and contact the Process Mapping team before its due date if amendments are required.'
      });
      sh.getRange(i + 1, 8).setValue('sent');
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes that your showing script works for the Spreadsheet of the columns "A" to "G". Please be careful about this.
- This modified script is for your sample Spreadsheet. When you changed the structure of the Spreadsheet, this script might not be able to be used. So please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [sendEmail(message)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailmessage)

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply this seem to have worked however I had the trigger running timebased the only issue now is its issuing continous emails after every minute. Previously the script would issue the email then once the email was sent, the word "sent" would be filled into the sheet which would prevent repeated emails. 

Do you know why this no longer works with the above script you have shown?

Just to confirm sent is still being inputted from the script onto the sheet however its function of preventing further emails is no longer working

Comment: After testing the script a few times from what you have provided these issues seems to occur 1), If the due date is 1 week on the table the script will continuously issue the email and apply "sent" onto the table though still send the emails, 2). If the due date is 1 month then it will issue the email however once "sent" is inputted into the sheet no further emails will be issued which is fine until this causes an issue when the date becomes to 1 week before then it will not issue the second reminder email advising its due.

Comment: In summary it should work as follows:  

1 month before issue email then do not issue any emails until 1 week. 1 email should be issued in each 1 month and 1 week and it should not continuously issue emails. Apologies im not sure how to resolve this

Comment: @Raj Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: thank you can confirm a new question has been posted and this marked as resolved